# Read from File, or STDIN

Tags: python, file, command-line, arguments, stdin

I've written a command line utility that uses getopt for parsing arguments given on the command line. I would also like to have a filename be an optional argument, such as it is in other utilities like grep, cut etc. So, I would like it to have the following usage

```
tool -d character -f integer [filename]
```

How can I implement the following?

- if a filename is given, read from the file.
- if a filename is not given, read from STDIN.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/how-do-i-make-python-programs-behave-like-proper-unix-tools/47543#47543

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In the simplest terms:

```
import sys
# parse command line
if file_name_given:
    inf = open(file_name_given)
else:
    inf = sys.stdin
```

At this point you would use `inf` to read from the file. Depending on whether a filename was given, this would read from the given file or from stdin.

When you need to close the file, you can do this:

```
if inf is not sys.stdin:
    inf.close()
```

However, in most cases it will be harmless to close `sys.stdin` if you're done with it.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Yes, both those functions will read from either a file or from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: I found another way to solve this problem, I blogged about it here http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/05/python-equivalent-of-cs-freopen.html and added an answer to this question as well.

Comment: @thefourtheye have deleted their answer; you probably don't need to click through to a blog to discover `sys.stdin  = open(file_name)`

Answer (score 101):

The [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module may do what you want - assuming the non-option arguments are in `args` then:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(args):
    print line
```

If `args` is empty then `fileinput.input()` will read from stdin; otherwise it reads from each file in turn, in a similar manner to Perl's `while(<>)`.

Comment: This was just as good of an answer, but isn't quite as generalizable. I will remember to use fileinput next time if appropriate.

Comment: Right, but if you're using `getargs` (as the OP is) then you probably just want to pass the leftover args rather than `sys.argv[1:]` (which is the default).

Comment: fileinput is a strange and annoying API, it forces you to use flagged arguments on the command line.

Comment: @ctpenrose It is not a fileinput design fault: distinguishing arguments that are the names of input files from other arguments is an issue that is inherent to the problem domain. Fileinput (especially with argparse) simplifies the use of a common pattern for doing this, which you can choose to use or not, but if have some other way of making the distinction, you can send a slice of sys.argv (or a different array of names altogether) to fileinput.input() - and you do not have to put in a fake sys.argv[0] when you explicitly pass an array.

Comment: If `args` is **an empty sequence**, it will read from stdin, yes. If it's `None`, then it will be as if it weren't supplied; i.e., `fileinput.input` will do its *own* parsing of the command line, and treat each token as a filename to open.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer to use "-" as an indicator that you should read from stdin, it's more explicit:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') if sys.argv[1] != "-" else sys.stdin as f:
    pass # do something here
```

Comment: Your solution will close `sys.stdin`, so `input` function calls after `with` statement will raise `ValueError`.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev  That may be true .. but most frequently the input is only used once in a script. This is a useful construct.

Answer (score 21):

I like the general idiom of using a context manager, but the (too) trivial solution ends up closing `sys.stdin` when you are out of the `with` statement, which I want to avoid.

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603000/874188), here is a workaround:

```
import sys
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def _smart_open(filename, mode='Ur'):
    if filename == '-':
        if mode is None or mode == '' or 'r' in mode:
            fh = sys.stdin
        else:
            fh = sys.stdout
    else:
        fh = open(filename, mode)
    try:
        yield fh
    finally:
        if filename != '-':
            fh.close()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if args == []:
        args = ['-']
    for filearg in args:
        with _smart_open(filearg) as handle:
            do_stuff(handle)
```

I suppose you could achieve [something similar with `os.dup()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26122548/874188) but the code I cooked up to do that turned out to be more complex and more magical, whereas the above is somewhat clunky but very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what exactly I was looking for. Very clear and straight forward solution.

Comment: This is also a useful bit of code to use when `argparse.FileType` just gets too annoying (which happens fairly often for me).

Answer (score 15):

To make use of python's `with` statement, one can use the following code:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin as f:
    # read data using f
    # ......
```

Comment: Your solution will close `sys.stdin`, so `input` function calls after `with` statement will raise `ValueError`.

Answer (score 13):

Not a direct answer but related.

Normally when you write a python script you could use the `argparse` package.
If this is the case you can use:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
```

> '?'. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible,
>   and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present,
>   the value from default will be produced.

and here we set default to `sys.stdin`;

so If there is a file it will read it , and if not it will take the input from stdin "Note: that we are using positional argument in the example above"

for more visit: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 8):

Switch to `argparse` (it's also part of the standard library) and use an
[`argparse.FileType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) with a default value of stdin:

```
import  argparse, sys

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('input', nargs='?',
  type=argparse.FileType(), default=sys.stdin)
args = p.parse_args()

print(args.input.readlines())
```

This will not let you specify encoding and other parameters for stdin,
however; if you want to do that you need to make the argument non-optional
and let `FileType` do its thing with stdin when `-` is given as an
argument:

```
p.add_argument('input', type=FileType(encoding='UTF-8'))
```

Take heed that this latter case will not honour binary mode (`'b'`) I/O. If
you need *only* that, you can use the default argument technique above, but
extract the binary I/O object, e.g., `default=sys.stdout.buffer` for
stdout. However, this will still break if the user specifies `-` anyway.
(With `-` stdin/stdout is always wrapped in a `TextIOWrapper`.)

If you want it to work with `-`, or have any other arguments you need to
provide when opening the file, you can fix the argument if it got wrapped
wrong:

```
p.add_argument('output', type=argparse.FileType('wb'))
args = p.parse_args()
if hasattr(args.output, 'buffer'):
    #   If the argument was '-', FileType('wb') ignores the 'b' when
    #   wrapping stdout. Fix that by grabbing the underlying binary writer.
    args.output = args.output.buffer
```

(Hat tip to [medhat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505388/107294) for
mentioning `add_argument()`'s `type` parameter.)

Answer (score 3):

A KISS solution is:

```
if file == "-":
    content = sys.stdin.read()
else:
    with open(file) as f:
        content = f.read()
print(content)   # Or whatever you want to do with the content of the file.
```

Comment: + if you wanted array of file lines, it's: `sys.stdin.readlines()`, `f.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if input_from_file:
    f = open(file_name, "rt")
else:
    f = sys.stdin
inL = f.readline()
while inL:
    print inL.rstrip()
    inL = f.readline()
```