# How to convert this python function to take sys.argv[1] instead of sys.stdin?

Tags: python, file, stream, sys

I have some confusion to differentiate the two options: **sys.argv[1]** and **sys.stdin** in my implementation. The python function is to read [[fastq]](https://github.com/lh3/readfq)files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

def readfq(fp):                                         # this is a generator function
    last = None                                         # this is a buffer keeping the last unprocessed line
    while True:                                         # mimic closure; is it a bad idea?
        if not last:                                    # the first record or a record following a fastq
            for l in fp:                                # search for the start of the next record
                if l[0] in '>@':                        # fasta/q header line
                    last = l[:-1]                       # save this line
                    break
        if not last: break
        name, seqs, last = last[1:].partition(" ")[0], [], None
        for l in fp:                                    # read the sequence
            if l[0] in '@+>':                           # This has a trick to skip the + row.
                last = l[:-1]                           # remember the sentenial variable last
                break
            seqs.append(l[:-1])                         # Append the sequence to seqs which is a list.

        if not last or last[0] != '+':                  # this is a fasta record
            yield name, ''.join(seqs), None             # yield a fasta record
            if not last: break
        else:                                           # this is a fastq record
            seq, leng, seqs = ''.join(seqs), 0, []
            for l in fp:                                # read the quality
                seqs.append(l[:-1])
                leng += len(l) - 1
                if leng >= len(seq):                    # have read enough quality
                    last = None
                    yield name, seq, ''.join(seqs);     # yield a fastq record
                    break
            if last:                                    # reach EOF before reading enough quality
                yield name, seq, None                   # yield a fasta record instead
                break

# Following is the tester
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    n, slen, qlen = 0, 0, 0
    for name, seq, qual in readfq(sys.stdin):           #Original line
#   **for name, seq, qual in readfq(sys.argv[1]):**        #This is what I want, but did not work.
        n += 1
        slen += len(seq)
        qlen += qual and len(qual) or 0
        print(seq)
print (n, '\t', slen, '\t', qlen)
```

I must have missed important parts to understand **sys.stdin** as **stream** and **sys.argv[1]** as **file object**, because the code does not work.

Closely related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744989/read-from-file-or-stdin?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussed about the using of **stdin** or **argv[1]** from command line as **argument parsing**, but my question is more about the difference between the contents of the two. More specifically, my this question is more about file stream(?), I think.

Comment: Does `readfq(open(sys.argv[1]))` work?

Comment: Thanks! I'm feeling embarrassed to have asked this question.